# When is usage still subsequent in a very long document?

Tags: abbreviations, repetition, military

We are supposed to spell out a military rank when used before a soldier's name, e.g.,

> Master Sergeant John Doe.

In **subsequent** usage, we are supposed to abbreviate the title to

> Master Sgt. John Doe

Style guides differ on the exact abbreviation with some preferring MSgt)

My question concerns the definition of **subsequent**. If you are writing a novel or any lengthy document, should you avoid abbreviating titles entirely or only abbreviate when the title appears several times in the same few pages?

Comment: I'd spell it out once per book, or at most once per chapter. *Subsequent* means all that follow the first full title are abbreviated.

Comment: To be honest if the book was a novel or biography in which M Sgt John Doe was a major character I'd get fed up of reading even the abbreviated form every time he was mentioned. I'd expect it to be shortened to Sgt Doe, Doe or even John (depending on the context) throughout most of the rest of the book.

Comment: Thank you BoldBen. You make a good point. In my case, he does not appear very often and has a son by the same name, so I need the distinction. I will definitely keep your recommendation in mind, however, if I confront this situation again. I think you are right.

Comment: If you're writing a novel, you're unlikely to be constrained by a specific style guide, so you can do what seems sensible. If you are writing a book for a publisher who has a style guide (commoner for academic works), then follow the style guide. This is a matter of style, not grammar.